# How do I properly shut down a BlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a BlockingQueue that processes work events on a single background thread. Various threads call `add` to add some work to the queue and a single background thread calls `take` to get the work and process it one a time. Eventually it may be time to stop the processing of work and I want to make sure that the callers who requested work either get their results or get `null` indicating their work was not done because the `BlockingQueue` is shutting down.

How do I cleanly stop accepting new work, the best I can think of is to set `BlockingQueue` field to `null` and then catch `NullPointerException` when `add` is called. Before setting the field to `null` I will keep a local copy of the pointer so I can drain it after it has stopped accepting work. I think that will work, but it seems a bit hacky, is there a proper way to do this?

Here is what the code looks like now:

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<Command> commandQueue = 
    new ArrayBlockingQueue<Command>(100, true);

public boolean addToQueue(Command command) {
  try {
    return commandQueue.add(command);
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    return false;
  }
}

@Override
public void run() {
  try {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      Command command = commandQueue.take();
      // ... work happens here
      // result is sent back to caller
      command.provideResponseData(response);
    }
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // Break out of the loop and stop
  }

  // TODO: stop accepting any new work, drain the queue of existing work 
  // and provide null responses
}
```

Comment: The javadoc of the blocking queue says:
  
`A BlockingQueue does not intrinsically support any kind of "close" or "shutdown" operation to indicate that no more items will be added. The needs and usage of such features tend to be implementation-dependent. For example, a common tactic is for producers to insert special end-of-stream or poison objects, that are interpreted accordingly when taken by consumers.`.  

I think poison objects would be a good solution.

Comment: Also, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974638/blocking-queue-and-multi-threaded-consumer-how-to-know-when-to-stop

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, use an `ExecutorService` or `ThreadPool`, but `submit` `Callable`s instead of mere `Runnable`s. Have your worker threads observe some stop signal (maybe an `AtomicBoolean` visible to all of them). If the flag has been set, make the `Callable`s return a special value to indicate that nothing was done. Callers must retain the `Future` returned by `submit` to `get` the `Callable`'s result.

Maybe I should elaborate some more. If you are currently using `Runnable`s, maybe wrap them in `Callable`s and, in `call`, check the stop flag. If you set the stop flag before you call ExecutorService.shutdown, it will complete the current job normally, but effectively cancel all remaining jobs, therefore draining the remaining queue fast. If you do not shut down, you can even reuse the ExecutorService after resetting the stop flag.

```
static enum EResult {
    Cancelled, Completed
}

static abstract class MyCallable implements Callable<EResult> {
    Runnable runner;

    public MyCallable( Runnable runner) {
        super();
        this.runner = runner;
    }
}

static AtomicBoolean cancelled = new AtomicBoolean( false);

static void main( String[] argv) {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println( "Done");
        }
    };

    Callable<EResult> callable = new MyCallable( runnable) {
        @Override
        public EResult call() throws Exception {
            if ( cancelled.get()) {
                return EResult.Cancelled;
            }
            runner.run();
            return EResult.Completed;
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 1);
    // while submitting jobs, change cancelled at some point
    Future<EResult> future = executorService.submit( callable);

    try {
        EResult completeOrNot = future.get();
        System.out.println( "result: " + completeOrNot);
    } catch ( InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch ( ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than work with BlockingQueue and a worker thread, consider using a single-thread ThreadPoolExecutor. Something like this:

```
private class CommandRunner implements Runnable {
    public CommandRunner(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void run() {
        // ... work happens here
        // result is sent back to caller
        command.provideResponseData(response);
    }
}

private ExecutorService commandExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public boolean addToQueue(Command command) {
    commandExecutor.submit(new CommandRunner(command));
}
```

And then your shutdown methods can delegate to the executor.

Comment: A single thread executor does look like the best solution since I said I did just have a single background thread. It looks like `shutdownNow()` does nearly what I want, the weird thing is it returns `Runnable`s for all the things waiting and I have to cast them as `FutureTask`s and cancel them.

Comment: then don't use shutdownNow. Not sure why you want to cancel anything you get from shutdownNow, since it is already clear that those jobs haven't run yet.