# Is queue.poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) method of LinkedBlockingQueue blocking in nature?

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I am using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` in a multithreaded environment, where multiple threads act as consumers. Currently I am using `queue.take()` to get the object from queue, which is causing the thread to wait indefinitely when queue becomes empty. To avoid this can I use `queue.poll()` method with specified timeout with the following conditions : 
1. all other threads are blocked for the specified timeout period except the current thread with call to `poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` method.

If not, is there any way I can achieve this ?

Any leads appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at the source code for that method. You'll find `takeLock.lockInterruptibly();` and `takeLock.unlock();` - draw your conclusions from that :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974638/blocking-queue-and-multi-threaded-consumer-how-to-know-when-to-stop

Comment: You have it back to front. The *current* thread is blocked for the timeout period, or shorter if an element arrives, and the other threads aren't blocked at all. Your requirement is incomprehensible.

Comment: @EJP, As per your comment, if current thread is blocked and other threads aren't blocked at all, this situation might cause current thread to starve to timeout.